# Create new segment in linker script while keeping default ones

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

I have created some special sections in a linked file and I want them to be in separated segments to have different page permissions.

In linker script, PHDRS command can specify segments in linked file. However, as the [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/phdrs.html) says, PHDRS will create no default-defined segments other than specified in the command. And I found no PHDRS command in `ld --verbose` output.

Is there any way to keep the default ones? Or what is the default specifications of segments so I can write them in my own linker script?

Comment: There's a writeup on how to tackle this problem by Stephen Krell over [here](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/srk21/blog/2017/02/14/). They also provide code. I'm sharing the link as a comment and not an answer because the approach shown is a workaround rather than a standard approach provided by the ld linker.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this when looking for similar answers.   It's late, but someone else might come across it.   To get the currently used linker script you can use `gcc -Wl,--verbose ...` or `ld --verbose ...` when linking, which will dump the script (and a bunch of other stuff) to stdout.   As far as I'm aware, there is no way to keep the default program headers and just append an entry to them without writing a custom script to parse the output of the above.  If you want to add a section on the other hand, apparently there's a trick with `objcopy --add-section` that allows you to add a section to an existing elf file.